# newcommand for rotation the mark angles automatically when use angle tikzlibrary

Tags: tikz-angles

I want to modify command `\Angle` which the mark angles auto rotation (see the appropriate).

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}
    \newcommand{\Angle}[3]
    {\draw pic[draw,angle radius=#2,"{\scriptsize #3}",angle eccentricity=1] {angle = #1}}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (5,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (45:5);
    \draw (B) -- (A) -- (C) -- cycle;
    \Angle{B--A--C}{1.5cm}{$\mid$};
    \Angle{C--B--A}{1cm}{$\mid\mid$};
    \Angle{A--C--B}{0.5cm}{$\mid\mid\mid$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not a direct answer but for certain things, one should use better tools. Here, it is `tkz-euclide`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\tkzDefPoint(0,0){C}
\tkzDefPoint(5,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(45:5){A}

\tkzDrawSegment[green!60!black](A,C)
\tkzDrawSegment[green!60!black](C,B)
\tkzDrawSegment[green!60!black](A,B)

\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5cm,color=cyan,mark=|](B,C,A)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=1cm,color=magenta,mark=||](C,A,B)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=1cm,color=olive,mark=|||](A,B,C)

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]